# Sender / Recipient position in letter?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I have the following template of a letter which I use to write a letter which I have to send to my university.

In the template the sender box is on the top right and the recipient box is on the left.

Is this position and the layout of the letter correct? Or else what would you change? By the way, it should be a swiss letter but I think it is everywhere the same.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass%%
  [fontsize=11pt,
   parskip=half,%%           Abstand zwischen Absaetzen
   fromalign=right,%%        Plazierung des Briefkopfs
   fromphone=on,%%           Telefonnummer im Absender
   fromrule=aftername,%%     Linie im Absender (aftername, afteraddress)
   fromemail=on,%%           Emailadresse
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{newcent}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape \LARGE}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{17mm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{275mm} % Abstand des Footers von oben
\@setplength{locwidth}{70mm} % Breite des Locationfeldes
\@setplength{locvpos}{55mm} % Abstand des Locationfeldes von oben
\@setplength{foldmarkhpos}{6.5mm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstraße 1\\12345 Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,(0)\,123\,123\,123\,1}%
\setkomavar{fromemail}{maxmustermann@mst.de}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft Kundennummer: 12345678}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize%
  \rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{.4pt}\\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar{fromemail}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
      \usekomavar{frombank}
    \end{tabular}%
    }%
}% 
\setkomavar{frombank}{Kto. 123\,123\,123\\
  BLZ 123\,123\,12\\
  Musterbank}

\newsavebox\signaturebox
\sbox\signaturebox{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=2.25em]{example-image.pdf}}\\[5pt]
    (\usekomavar{fromname})
  \end{tabular}}
\setkomavar{signature}{\usebox{\signaturebox}}%
\renewcommand*\raggedsignature{\raggedright}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}

\begin{letter}{Maxi Musterfrau\\Nebenstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Swiss letter are *not* "generic letters". They follow a particular norm, the Swiss norm SN 010130, which is implemented by [the `chletter` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chletter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markus Kohm, the author of KOMA-Script, has written an `lco` file for swiss letters.  How to use it and how to change it you can read (in German, but you can read/understand that)  on the homepage of KOMA-Script following [this link](http://www.komascript.de/node/1445).

There you can also find a remark that there are two different styles for swiss letter possible. Choose that one you like (I can't know that).  See the `lco` files `SN.lco` und `SNleft.lco`, you can call them as class options in `scrltr2`.

To show you the call of `SNleft.lco` I stripped down your given code to the basics.  See line 2 of the code (marked with `<===`): there is the "letter class option" file `SNleft.lco` called. This does only work with KOMA-Script, `scrltr2` class.  BTW: You can write an own `lco` file, containing your personal datas.  Details please see the excellent documentation of KOMA-Script (type `texdoc KOMA-Script` on the terminal) and choose the english or german version.

```
\documentclass[%
  SNleft,%         Schweizer Briefvorlage: SNleft oder SN <=============
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% personal Data, could be put into separate lco file
\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Hauptstraße 1\\12345 Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+49\,(0)\,123\,123\,123\,1}%
\setkomavar{fromemail}{maxmustermann@mst.de}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterhausen}


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Maxi Musterfrau\\Nebenstraße 1\\12345 Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
Brieftext
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

BTW: If you want to have a look into the existing `.lco` files, just follow the path `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\koma-script\SNleft.lco` (this path is valid for windows, 64bit installation).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used lco files before. I would prefer the style with the recipient (Empfängeranschrift) to the left. Please, could you make a small example? It is very urgent in writing the letter.